# How to locate elements with same class but different incremental ids in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, ui-automation

## names=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'classnamecomeshere')]")
for name in names:
if name.text == "123456789-0":
name.click()
break

## User

with the same class there are id with increasing number 123456789-2 etc

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Can you elaborate the question? Please provide some context and not just the code snippets.

Comment: <td role="cell" headers="Customer" test-id="customer" class="Tdstyle__StyledTD"><span aria-hidden="true" class="Tdstyle__StyledMobileHeading">Customer</span><a id="234567890-0" component-id="Link" class="Linkstyle__StyledAnchor">Name</a></td>

Comment: Name and Customer is visible in UI.  Customer is column name in the table and Name is one of the block in the column.  so                                                     --------Customer                                                                                                                  Name                                                                                                                                   Name                                                                                                                                  Name

Answer (score 1):

few things :

Instead of

```
*[contains(@class,'actualclassname')]
```

use this  :

```
//a[contains(@class,'actualclassname')]
```

and Instead of

```
 if name.id == "idnumber":
```

use this :

```
if name.text == "idnumber":
```

Code would look something like this :

```
names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'actualclassname')]")
for name in names:
    if name.text == "idnumber":
       name.click()
       break
```

Comment: <td role="cell" headers="Customer" test-id="customer" class="Tdstyle__StyledTD"><span aria-hidden="true" class="Tdstyle__StyledMobileHeading">Customer</span><a id="234567890-0" component-id="Link" class="Linkstyle__StyledAnchor">Name</a></td> –

Comment: 1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
1 scenario passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
2 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined.    but button is not getting clicked